# django and bash in Debian

Tags: django, shell

I have setup django with mod_wsgi and apache. Now I want to use http to complete the svn update task. 
You know, if we want to update the specific website on the server, we have to ssh to the server and cd to the directory and use svn update, it's too complicated, so I want to send a get request and let the python do the stuffs for me.

Here is the problem that I can run the bash in the Debian and it successes :

```
import os

def hello(request):
    os.chdir("/var/www-chengtoo-new-Test/")
    os.system("svn update")
    os.chdir("/var/TestWebsiteTool/hello")
    os.mkdir("hahaha");
    return HttpResponse("hello")
```

every works fine except "svn update". so is anyone can help me? I just want to figure out why it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `os.system` executes any commands within their own thread, using `sh`, and is unaffected by the `chdir` you're running first.

So essentially, when you're calling `svn update`, it's likely being executed against either the system root, or some other directory depending on your OS configuration.

You'll need to do:

```
os.system("cd /var/www-chengtoo-new-Test/; svn update")
```

A better way to handle this, in my opinion, is the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) library:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("svn update", shell=True, cwd="/var/www-chengtoo-new-Test/")
```

Comment: I have tried the two methods above, but I found they still didn't work.

Comment: no error, just didn't excute "svn update", you know, I just try to delete a file in /var/www-chengtoo-new-Test/ and then modify the views.py in my app directory as you said, then I request the url and the deleted file just didn't restore.

Comment: What happens when you shell into your server an execute the command directly?

Comment: No clue then. Could be a permission thing, or a PATH problem. You need to capture the output and see what's happening. Try using subprocess.call and printing it's return. http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess